# Google App Script: Publish Script as owner

Tags: google-apps-script, publish

I have a script which is bound to a document. Initially this script was written by friend, now I am taking care of this. I want to publish this script as add on. I have done all the formalities, as suggested by google. 
When I clicked on **Deploy as Docs Web add-on** [image] it gave me error, that Only owner of script can publish the script.

Is there any way to change the owner the of script.

Comment: Looks like you are working on someone else's project. Hence the issue. Try this. Create a new blank doc. Open script editor. Paste the code and try.

Comment: Why would there ever be a way for a non-owner to become an owner that is **callable by the non-owner**? Only the owner of the file can change its ownership. Contact your friend and have them transfer the file...

Comment: even I also thought this. I will try to both ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a copy the script file and deploying that copy.

[image: screenshot]